# Git checkout for large repos in Azure

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019

I need to know more about my Azure server 2019 situated at Nederlands (Europe) and if I try to do a checkout from India (Asia-Pacific) for any 2GB Azure repo, will it take more time?

Meaning if we have any local cache server, will it help us in faster checkout or clones over pipeline. If really it helps then I came across GVFS so then I have query if GVFS is better or any local cache.

Please advise and share reference, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your first question is more like network related. If you  have low latency (only one network hop) between server machine and dev environment, it should definitely take less time.

> Meaning if we have any local cache server, will it help us in faster
>   checkout or clones over pipeline.

No, we do not have any local cache server. But we provide a **Clean** option before a build runs. You should be able to select the Clean setting from the properties of the Get sources task in your pipeline and select one of the following options.

[image]

In general, **for faster performance of your self-hosted agents, don't clean the repo.** In this case, to get the best performance, make sure you're also building incrementally by disabling any Clean option of the task or tool you're using to build.

More details please take a look at our official doc here: [Clean build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#clean-build)